# How to make Group By With multi inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

i try to make filttering for selected data using inner join 
i have 3 tables i should join it 
this is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM products_products
    INNER JOIN products_products_translations on products_products.id = products_products_translations.entry_id
    INNER JOIN products_products_related on products_products.id = products_products_related.entry_id
    INNER JOIN upload_files on products_products_related.related_id = upload_files.related_id
WHERE products_products_translations.locale = 'tr'
GROUP BY products_products_related.entry_id;
```

And this is the error that i got

> Query 1 ERROR: Expression #35 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
>   'shop.products_products_translations.id' which is not functionally
>   dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: You are using `select * from` without specifying the columns you want to group. This `*` will concatenate the rows from all 3 tables and you didn't specify a group by clause for all 3 tables. That's why it is ambiguous for the database to group the results. Either specify the columns in select clause or use unambiguous group by statement.

Comment: You usually don't combine GROUP BY with SELECT DISTINCT, since the GROUP BY eliminates duplicates.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish would help.  A non-functioning query does not convey what you really want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `distinct`, and add `products_products_related.entry_id, COUNT(*)`

```
SELECT products_products_related.entry_id, COUNT(*)
FROM products_products
         INNER JOIN products_products_translations on products_products.id = products_products_translations.entry_id
         INNER JOIN products_products_related on products_products.id = products_products_related.entry_id
         INNER JOIN upload_files on products_products_related.related_id = upload_files.related_id
WHERE products_products_translations.locale = 'tr'
GROUP BY products_products_related.entry_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly select the columns that are not coming after the group by clause.

The reason is when you group by any column, entry_id for example, you'll have single row for each entry_id. But, each entry_id has many rows in the original table with many different values in the other columns.

Therefore, you need to tell the query how to aggregate the columns which are not the columns you decided to group by.

You can aggregate them by COUNT(...) or SUM(...), or many other functions.

The solution would be something like the following:

```
SELECT products_products_related.entry_id, MAX(Column1), MIN(Column2) /*etc...*/
FROM products_products
    INNER JOIN products_products_translations on products_products.id = products_products_translations.entry_id
    INNER JOIN products_products_related on products_products.id = products_products_related.entry_id
    INNER JOIN upload_files on products_products_related.related_id = upload_files.related_id
WHERE products_products_translations.locale = 'tr'
GROUP BY products_products_related.entry_id;
```